# Cannot import my store file into App.js error: 'store' should be listed in the project's dependencies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

> 'store' should be listed in the project's dependencies

For some reason I can't import my store into App.js

[image]

Here you can see that App.js and store.js are at the same level:

[image]

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect, Provider } from 'react-redux';

import Routes from './config/Routes';
import { setSearch } from './actions';
import localCoins from './coins.json';

// Store
import store from 'store';

class App extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.setSearch(localCoins);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Routes />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  setSearch: (...args) => { dispatch(setSearch(...args)); }
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

**store.js**

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

// Reducers
import reducers from './reducers';

/* eslint-disable no-underscore-dangle */
const reduxDevToolsExtension = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__;
/* eslint-enable */

const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    ...reducers
  }),
  reduxDevToolsExtension && reduxDevToolsExtension(),
  applyMiddleware(
    thunk
  )
);

export default store;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you meant `import store from './store';`

you are missing the `./` that indicates that is a project file not an installed dependency

Comment: Thanks! From another project we had fixed the absolute paths and I just broke out the store code into it's own file in this project. 4 more mins!